# Google sheets using setvalue doesn't trigger refresh of API endpoint

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

We are using =IMPORTDATA("URL") function of google sheets to pull in a csv that has data. The =IMPORTDATA("URL") is inputted in cell A1. The data refreshes periodically and we would like to reinput the =IMPORTDATA("URL") in order to refresh the feed.

Currently this is done via a script + trigger in Google sheets

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssSet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
ssSet.getRange('A1').setValue('=IMPORTDATA("URL")');
```

The script runs fine, we see the sheet clear and the value in A1 updated and the data feeds in however the data has not refreshed. My initial hypothesis is that setValue doesn't trigger a new call to the URL. The data updates fine if we do it manually ie delete cell A1 and copy in the formula =IMPORTDATA("URL") again.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Script execution does not trigger sheet events.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @tehhowch - is there a way to trigger sheet events?

Comment: You could use an [installable time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run the update every hour, for example.

Comment: Just call the event handler from your method...

Comment: The script is triggered every minute via G Suite application triggers. 

Every time the script is triggered the sheet is cleared and the =IMPORTDATA("URL") is inserted in cell A1.

However the old data appears and it doesn't seem to be pulling in new data from the URL. When we insert it manually we see "Loading..." appear in cell A1 before the data is loaded. This doesn't occur via the triggered script.